# Drupal 7 check logged in user has both roles in tpl file?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, users

I want to print in a page--node--17.tpl.php a code to check for roles from the logged in user and then determine what should be shown, so basically a user must have BOTH roles A and C and if they do i print xxx
If they have roles A and B i write yyy
if they have roles B and C i print zzz

So the code below can check for one role, but how do i do both.. its important that BOTH roles need to be there, a user with just one of the roles will not qualify.

thank u

```
<?php
  global $user;
  // Check to see if $user has the administrator user role.
  if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    // Do something.
  }
?>
```

also i have this code but i think this is only checking one of the roles, so it checks for either A or B

```
<?php
global $user;
$check = array_intersect(array('moderator', 'administrator'), array_values($user->roles));
    if (empty($check) ? FALSE : TRUE) {
    // is admin
    } else {
    // is not admin
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have to say, just seeing "Checking if user has role", and separately, "in tpl file" makes me draw a sharp breath. Both of these indicate that something is _quite_ wrong with what you are doing. You should _strongly_ consider a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simple as:

```
global $user;

if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles)) &&  in_array('moderator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    // is admin
} else {
    // is not admin
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_intersect()` returns the intersected array, so your condition will pass if *either* of the roles are present.

There are different ways to approach it but this is probably the simplest:

```
$check = array_intersect(array('moderator', 'administrator'), array_values($user->roles));
if (count($check) == 2) {
  // ...
```

On a slightly separate note, there's a bit of redundancy in your code

```
if (empty($check) ? FALSE : TRUE)
```

Would be simply

```
if (empty($check))
```